# Does Rails Auto-Assign ID's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm trying to sort my users in my controller, and I wanted to sort them by id number. My question is, does rails automatically assign orders an id when they are created, or do I need to add that to the create function in my create action in my controller? For example, can I say this:

```
def index
  @users = User.all.order(:WHAT TO PUT HERE???????)
end
```

Would I put :id in the space? If I did so, would I need to define id somewhere else or is this something ruby does on the back end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases Rails would return you records sorted by id. But you should not rely on Rails as  sorting is database-specific.

To explicitly add sorting by id you should use:

```
def index
  @users = User.order(:id)
end
```

Id is automatically added, you don't need to declare it anywhere.

Comment: As far as i know the default is sorting by database natural order. Which is not the same thing as primary key based sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Rails only helps you create the table via migrations. When a migration creates a table it automatically adds the id column as a primary key set to auto increment. So why you create records it's actually the database that adds the id, or as aforementioned, it auto increments it +1 from the last id. Therefore, when you use ActiveRecord to create a record you don't need to specify an id.

Now for your main question: you can pass the name of the column to the `order` method when you want to sort ascending by that column. You don't need to call `all` though.

So just do this:

```
User.order(:id)
```

That will sort from lower ids to higher. To do the opposite:

```
User.order("id DESC")
```

This will give your the most recently created records first by sorting from higher ids to lower.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort User by ID

```
 @users = User.order(:id)  #ASC default

 @users = User.order('id ASC')  #ASC explicit

 @users = User.order('id DESC')  #DESC explicit
```

Answer (score 0):

...and never forget the `User.order('-id')` unary minus shortcut...